# Unable to find any jvms matching version 1.7 while starting neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, jvm

I am using Mac OS X Yosemite and I had Java8 JRE installed

> [image: image1]
>   [image: image2]

but, when I start neo4j, it is unable to find any JVM's matching version 1.7

> [image: image3]

Comment: Your images tell you everything you need. You have JRE 1.8, but you need JRE 1.7.

Comment: but jre8 is backward compatible to java7, it should not have been a problem. meanwhile, my eclipse project uses java8, so if i downgrade to java7, there will be problems.

Comment: I think technically not supported, but out of curiosity I ran 2.1.6 on 1.8 and do not recall any ill effects.  Looking at your screen caps it looks like the server started ok. If you need the listed supported java version though you would need to switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've installed java 8 while neo4j is searching for java 7. So install java 7 and set it as your default jvm/jre and it should execute correctly.

Comment: isn't java8 backward compatible to java7?

Comment: I sovled the problem by downgrading java8 to java7, but stil, I wonder why I can not use java8 since it is backward compatible.

Comment: @user3077801 Seems like neo4j isn't looking for jre/jvm_home but specifically for java7 home. That's the problem.

Comment: I don't have the luxury of going back to Java7. Is there a timeframe for Java8 support in Neo4j?

Answer (score 11):

Neo4J startup script looks for `JAVA_HOME` and if it is not set defaults to setting it to Java v1.7. So, set your `JAVA_HOME` in your `.bash_profile` file.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Then, either restart your Terminal or do

```
$ source .bash_profile
```

Now, if you restart Neo4J you shouldn't see the error message.

Comment: Worked as a charm using Java 8.